# Python web app with Flask, updating image tag on view with button tag

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm developing a WEB APP with Python and Flask. I want to display an image using an html image tag and a button tag to open the browser and choose an image and display it inside the  tag by updating it using Jinja. How could I do that ?

main.py:

'''

```
image_filepath = ''

def browse_img_file():
    global image_filepath
    path = easygui.fileopenbox(msg="", title="choose an image", multiple=False, filetypes=['.png', '.jpg', '.gif'])
    image_filepath = path

@app.route("/")
def index():
    global image_filepath
    if image_filepath == '':
        image_load = url_for('static', filename='/images/no-img.png')
    else:
        image_load = image_filepath
    return render_template("index.html", image=image_load)


@app.route("/upload")
def upload():
    global image_filepath
    try:
        browse_img_file()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

index.html:

```
<div id="CONTENT">
    <p>Choose your image.</p>

    <div class="img">
        <image src="{{ image }}"></image>
    </div>

    <a href="{{ url_for('upload', image=image) }}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload an image</button>
    </a>

</div>
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

i think the solution is to use `<input>` instead of `<a>` here:

```
<div id="CONTENT">
<p>Choose your image.</p>
<div class="img">
<image src="{{ image }}"></image>
</div>
 <!-- <a href="{{ url_for('upload', image=image) }}"> -->
<input type="file">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload an image</button>
</a>
</div>
```

source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_file_upload_button.asp)

Comment: I tired:
```
<form action="{{ url_for('upload', image=image) }}">
    <input type="file" id="{{ image }}" name="filename">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload an image</button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```
but it does not seem to work, the browser opens, I select the image but the image does not appear. Even when I right click, open picture in new tab. the address of the specific page "about: blank # blocked".

Comment: this [link,](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_file_uploading.htm) tutorial  might help you

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling the 'upload' route, you are only returning the 'index' page. aren't you supposed to return the image_path too for jinja to load the 'image'?

```
return render_template("index.html", image=image_filepath)
```

I think returning this from the 'upload' route should work. [image]

[image]